# using TableLayoutPanel and dynamic Combobox in windows form C#

Tags: c#

I need some serious help with this. I've searched on the forums, googled, and expermimented as much as I can....all to no avail.

Here's the problem.

I'm using a TableLayoutPanel to dynamically configure a form based on values from a database. 
To the TableLayoutPanel, I dynamically add -

- 1 Label,
- 1 Textbox,
- 1 Button,
- 1 Combobox

**Here's the root of the problem -**

> If I have 2 or more rows in the TableLayoutPanel, all the Comboboxes
>   change at the same time.

*What do I have to do to only get 1 Combobox to change at a time ?*

Comment: Can you post your code? We might be able to better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

The datasource is the same, so it treats any change in one combobox connected to the datasource as a change to any other connected comboboxes. To get around that simply make a temporary string array and copy over the information to that array from the original source, from there simply have it be the datasource of the combobox.